# How to Remove Extra separator Line in Gantt Charts graph in anyChart

Tags: angular, anychart

i was looking at the example playground in anychart in following URL

https://playground.anychart.com/gallery/Gantt_Charts/Human_Resource_Chart

then suddenly i found a big line seperator between names and graph as shown in below image

[image]

i wish to remove this line which is extra from graph
i mean how to remove line marked in yellow in below image as marked as yellow 
now i want to remove this 
so how to achieve this

i can see this problem exist in most of the graphs playgrounds

anychart.scroler

Answer (score 0):

The chart always renders the splitter from the top edge of the chart to the bottom edge. You can avoid drawing the extra splitter line by decreasing the chart height to the required bounds or to the last row position.

The sample of using the second approach you can check by the link in the comment below.